# Generate a 100 GB Postgres relation quickly in Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, caching, performance-testing, database-performance

I am trying to generate a 100 GB postgres table quickly. I need this relation for prewarming the buffer cache. I have tried using bytea and text fields. This keeps the actual relation small and a large TOAST table. The tricky part is that the TOAST table cannot be loaded into the cache due to permission issues. I am wondering if anyone has experience creating such a big table quickly?

Comment: What is the point of "warming" the buffer cache with garbage?

Comment: This is for cold-cache performance testing. The ideal way is to flush the buffer cache or drop caches. But I am running it on a managed service on the cloud and I am unable to do so. Hence, I want to fill the cache with garbage to evict the relations that have been cached from the previous run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it would be the absolute fastest, but this should be pretty good:

```
create unlogged table j (x text);
alter table j alter x set storage plain ;
insert into j select repeat('a',4100) from generate_series(1,13107200);
```

Setting the storage clause like this will disable TOAST, both out-of-line storage and in-line compression.  Making it unlogged will prevent it from streaming to any replicas or WAL archives.  Sizing it to over half a page ensures that only one row is written per page.  It will still consume storage on the primary, but I don't think there is any way around that with managed services.

You might want to populate it with COPY FREEZE to avoid the need to vacuum, but I don't think you would be able to get that to work well on managed services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pgbench` to generate fake banking data and specify how much data you want. It is fast, shows progress, predictable, and well documented.

As an example, the following command generates about ~62GB of data in my testing pretty quickly.

```
pgbench -iq -s 5000 --unlogged -I dtg -U postgres -h my_database_hostname_ip DBNAME
```

The `-s` option is the *scaling factor* that controls the amount of data generated. Per [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html), a scale of 1X generates about 100K of data rows. Through empirical testing, a scale of 5000 gives us about ~63 GB of data.

The `-I dtg` specifies specifically the init steps and we are chosing to skip vacuum and index. Feel free to omit if you do plan to do more with the fake data. In my case, I just wanted to quickly fill up the DB for IO and bandwidth testing.

You can monitor size of your DB by executing:

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('DBNAME')) AS size;
```